# Changes in Pandas DataFrames don't preserved after end of for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of Pandas DataFrames and I want to perform some operations on them. To be more precise, I want to clean their names and add new column. So I have written the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from janitor import clean_names
rng = np.random.RandomState(2019)
dataset = [pd.DataFrame(rng.randint(0, 10, (3, 3)), columns = ['Column A', 'Column B', 'Column C']) for i in range(4)]
for df in dataset:
    df = df.clean_names()
    df['column_d'] = df['column_a'] + df['column_b']
```

However, the changes are not preserved despite explicite assignment. The following code returns the original DataFrame:

```
dataset[1]
    Column A    Column B    Column C
0          8           5           3
1          0           2           5
2          7           8           5
```

What am I missing?

Comment: After `df = df.clean_names()` `df` no longer refers to the original `DataFrame`.

Comment: Isn't original `DataFrame` replaced? There's some obvious misundarstanding from my side, but how can it be corrected?

Comment: No, where do you think it would be replaced?

Comment: `df = df.clean_names()` here. I understand it as something like `df.clean_names(inplace = True)`. But there obviously is some difference in comparison to other languages (eg. R).

Comment: No, the first one returns a new object without touching the original. The second one mutates the original and returns `None`. That is the point of having `inplace` as an argument.

Comment: I mean, if  `clean_names` had that argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what is happening:

```
for df in dataset:
```

This makes `df` to refer to an item in the list in each iteration.

```
df = df.clean_names()
```

`df.clean_names()` returns a new object, different from `df` itself. The assignment makes `df` to refer to that new object instead of the original.

```
df['column_d'] = df['column_a'] + df['column_b']
```

This changes `df` in place but it is not the original object, the original remains untouched.

You should get what you want by using an index to the list to actually replace each item. Something like this:

```
for i, df in enumerate(dataset):
    df = df.clean_names()
    df['column_d'] = df['column_a'] + df['column_b']
    dataset[i] = df
```

Not the prettiest thing in the world but I don't have time to think of something better.

Comment: Do you know how my task could be accomplished in alternative way? I want to automatically convert all names to snake case naming style