# Looping over dataframe list

Tags: python, pandas

```
d1 = {'id': ['a','b','c'], 'ref': ['apple','orange','banana'], 'value':[1,2,3]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)

d2 = {'id': ['a','b','c'], 'ref': ['apple','orange','banana'], 'value':[1,2,3]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)

for df in [df1, df2]:
    df = df[df['id'] == 'a']
```

I have a list of dataframes I'd like to run the same operations on. The loop works, however, the outputs aren't as desired. Above, I'm just running a simple filter, but the changes aren't saved... how can I fix this?

UPDATE - Also tried looping through dict and did not work:

```
df_dict = {'df1':df1,'df2':df2}
for df in df_dict.keys():
   df_dict[df] = df_dict[df][df_dict[df]['id'] == 'a']
```

Comment: the changes *aren't saved... thats the problem

Comment: Comprendez @chicagobeast12.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changes in Pandas DataFrames don't preserved after end of for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56698637/changes-in-pandas-dataframes-dont-preserved-after-end-of-for-loop)

Comment: 'clean_names' did not work for me here

Comment: it would be easier to store your dataframes in a dictionary, is it possible for you?

Comment: Yes, this would probably be much simpler lol. I'll just do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why does your loop not assign to df1, df2?**

---

The answer has to do with `for` loop semantics.
A typical `for` loop ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement))

```
for x in expression_list:
    #statements
```

makes assignments to the name/variable `x` to the objects returned by the iterable that `expression_list` evaluates to. If `x` was a variable before the `for`, then the assignments in the `for` overwrite what it was previously and will persist beyond the `for`. If `x` was not a variable before the `for`, essentially, in the first iteration of the loop, a new name/variable `x` is introduced into the program, originally pointing to the first object returned by the iterable; this name will still persist - after the `for`, `x` will be a variable that refers to the last assigned-to object in the `for`.

Your code

```
for df in [df1, df2]:
    df = df[df['id'] == 'a']
    print(df)
```

with output

```
  id    ref  value
0  a  apple      1
  id    ref  value
0  a  apple      1
```

does not have your desired effect of assigning to `df1` and `df2` because in the first iteration of the loop, `df` is a **name** that refers to the object associated with the name `df1`. Once you modify `df` (assign it to another object), all you have done is made `df` refer to another object. Similarly for the second iteration of the loop.

As is clear by my addition of the `print` statements, your right-hand-side of the assignment is evaluating to your desired result, but it is assigning it to the name `df`, not the names `df1` and `df2`!

After the start of the `for` loop, `df` is a name (or variable) just like any other variable. If you print `df` after the `for` loop you will get

```
  id    ref  value
0  a  apple      1
```

which is the last value that was assigned to `df` (i.e. from the last iteration of the loop).

**Potential Solution**

---

One way to do what you want is to use the `DataFrame`s as values to a dictionary.

```
import pandas as pd

# data
d1 = {'id': ['a','b','c'], 'ref': ['apple','orange','banana'], 'value':[1,2,3]}
d2 = {'id': ['a','b','c'], 'ref': ['apple','orange','banana'], 'value':[1,2,3]}

# dict storing DataFrames
d = {'df1': pd.DataFrame(d1), 'df2': pd.DataFrame(d2)}

for key in d:
    d[key] = d[key][d[key]['id'] == 'a']

print(d['df1'])
print(d['df2'])
```

Output

```
  id    ref  value
0  a  apple      1
  id    ref  value
0  a  apple      1
```

Comment: So it's just not getting stored. I was hoping to simply loop through a list of df's, perform the same operation, and then when I call each df, they would be cleaned. A previous comment is likely the best option (store df's in a dictionary) and loop over the dict.keys() instead

Comment: I agree @chicagobeast12. My first instinct is to use a dictionary.

Comment: Pleasure! I have updated my answer to include how you might do it with a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`drop()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) with `inplace=True` to filter the original `pd.DataFrame`, which was defined previously.

The reason why the solution works, is that drop can edit the original df by setting inplace=True. In your solution you work on a copy of the df, but do not alter the original df1 or df2.

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = {'id': ['a','b','c'], 'ref': ['apple','orange','banana'], 'value':[1,2,3]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)

d2 = {'id': ['a','b','c'], 'ref': ['apple','orange','banana'], 'value':[1,2,3]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)


for df in [df1, df2]:
    df.drop(df[df['id'] != 'a'].index,inplace=True)
```

**Output:**

```
  id    ref  value
0  a  apple      1
```

Comment: Clever!  I like this solution.

Comment: Solution works for the example operation provided, however since I'm running a set of operations (another being df.columns = col_lst), I'm not sure how to handle operations like those, so was looking for an explanation as to why looping over a df list like this doesn't seem to work, or a more dynamic solution (since not every operation has an 'inplace' parameter)

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the df.columns=col_lst? The reason why the above works, is that drop can edit the original df by setting inplace=True. In your solution you work on a copy of the df, but do not alter the original df1 or df2.

Comment: @chicagobeast12 See my answer

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your dataframes are all going to be `"df" + i`:

```
for i, df in enumerate([df1, df2]):
    df.name = "df" + str(i+1)
    globals()[df.name] = df[df['id'] == 'a']
```

Comment: This would obviously also work if you provided a `zip()` of a list of dataframes, and a list of those dataframe variable names as strings).

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning df a value of the Dataframe by calling the pd.Dataframe function, therefore the df can never equal anything that is not the Dataframe.

Your code calls to reassign a value to df only representative of a column for id.
Perhaps only reassigning the id value would be more optimal for what you are looking for:

```
d1 = {'id': ['a','b','c'], 'ref': ['apple','orange','banana'],'value':[1,2,3]} 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)

d2 = {'id': ['a','b','c'], 'ref': ['apple','orange','banana'],'value':[1,2,3]} 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)

for df in [df1, df2]:
    df['id'] == 'a'
```

Let me know if this is what you are looking for.